# Skill to Hindcast

Tags: adjectives

I wonder whether it's correct to say *hindcastive*, similarly to what we do with *predictive* to denote the ability to predict. If not, what would be an equivalent term? possibly:

- *retrodictive* (in the OED)
- back-casting
- retrospective forecasting

*NB*: the term isn't even listed in the OED, unlike in Webster's, but it's known in scientific literature.

Example sentence:

2002   *Annals of the American Academy of Political and Social Science*  583 18/1   *Not merely a prediction as to the future course of the illness, but..a retrodiction of what had already taken place.*

and hence

1932   H. H. Price *Perception* vii. 201   Any perceptual act is bound to be among other things a prediction,..and in the same way it must be ‘retrodictive’ as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Hindcast is in dictionaries, as is retrodictive, but hindcastive is not. Both refer to estimating or predicting an earlier state of a system from the current state.

Comment: "Hindcast" is rare word which is only understood in certain specialties.

Comment: @HotLicks - I thought it was when you moon your web camera.

Comment: Evidence of research (linked, attributed quotes) rather than hearsay needs to be given. Xanne has to interpret what you say. // If in no dictionary, it's not in the standard lexicon. In various domains, novel terms are acceptable, but that is not a matter for ELU. Acceptability is dependent on the local usage circle. For instance, '1010 acid' was a well-known shorthand for a reagent in a lab complex I once worked in. But off-topic on ELU.

Comment: People normally don't say *forecastive* either (even though somebody who insisted on saying it would probably be understood). Is there any reason why you resist using *retrodictive*, which would be unproblematic?

Comment: Just trying to find out whether hindcastive would be acceptable as an opposite of predictive, as *hindcast* has good reception in mathematical simulation community, more than retrodictive.

Comment: If you are interested only in whether some word would be regarded as acceptable within a specific community, rather than among English speakers at large, you are likely to get a more useful answer by directing the question specifically to people from that community. There are many terms that may be accepted within a particular community, as a part of its jargon, even though they are not accepted otherwise.

Comment: I do wonder if "hindsight" doesn't fit the need for a term in many contexts.

Answer (score 1):

A retrodiction is a prediction about what you expect to see or not see in a record of the past. We do not expect to see evidence of large mammals dating earlier than 65 million years ago. Hindcast is an interesting possibility but it will be difficult to make it seem appropriate for use without a good context for it to live in.

Comment: Thanks Elliot. Not sure that I understand your reasoning about hindcast though. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: This answer needs references.

Answer (score 0):

Postdiction according to wikipedia is an 'explanation after the fact'.

Witten, a famous physicist, once said that string theory postdicted some phenomena that had already been explained. I forget what.

Again, according to wikipedia theologians use this in the latin form: *vaticinium ex eventu*, meaning 'foretelling after the event'.